# How to disable autosizing of images into PowerPoint 2016?

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint-2016

I have a VBScript which copies images from Qlikview tool and pastes them into PowerPoint. Earlier we were using Office 2010 in that this worked pretty well however we are now migrated to Office 2016 and the images are all distorted. The reason is Office 2016 resizes the images on its own to fit the slide(page) and then the VBScript used is also resizing it which is really changing the resolutions making the PPTs good for nothing. Can anyone please suggest how I can disable the auto sizing of images in PowerPoint 2016?

Any help is appreciated here.

Thanks
Yash

Comment: Can you post your script here?

Comment: Hi - the script is below

Comment: the script is too big, I can't paste it here.